# Как зазывать всех людей в телеграмм боте на питоне?

Tags: python, telegram

Как зазывать всех людей в телеграмм боте на питоне? (желательно на аиограм если возможно)

Как к примеру зазывала бот в телеграмме

Comment: Вам ответили в вашем предыдущем вопросе. Может стоить сначала начать язык учить, а потом уже ботов делать?

Comment: я тут имел ввиду код‍♀️

Comment: Обратитесь на фриланс биржу, вам за оплату напишут ваш код